# I have an error while using eclipse?

Tags: java

The error says that "the container 'JRE system library [java se 1.6]' references non existing library 'C:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar'"

Comment: When did this error start to happen?

Comment: the moment I launch eclipse

Comment: This looks like you have the incorrect JRE lib added in your eclipse path. Check the eclipse config file (eclipse.ini).

Comment: I think the version of your JRE and the path may be a hint to the source of the problem.

Comment: Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: @name123: CoolBeans did suggest a solution...

Answer (score 1):

`references non existing library`  suggests that you are referring to something but Eclipse cannot find it there. Like *CoolBeans* said, you have an incorrect JRE lib on your path.

I would suggest that you manually check if the file exists. Have you recently uninstalled Java and reinstalled a newer version ?